# Querying by date range in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am trying to show all entries of my firebase within two timestamps. My Firebase setup looks like this

```
https://my_firebase_url/users/7b49e1f4-a7c2-4d42-b2ef-145b0ff83d21/orders:

{
    "1234": {
        "size" : 45,
        "deliveryDate" : 1460844000000
},
{
    "1342": {
        "size" : 23,
        "deliveryDate" : 1243845000000
}
```

Here is my query:

```
new Firebase('https://my_firebase_url/users/7b49e1f4-a7c2-4d42-b2ef-145b0ff83d21/orders')
            .orderByChild('deliveryDate')
            .startAt(1400000000000)
            .endAt(1500000000000)
            .once('value', function (snap) {
                console.log(snap.val());
            });
```

My console window should display the order with ref.nr `1234`, but instead it displays `null`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You are using different Firebase references in above snippets. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Yeah, they should. This was just an error on my part when copy/pasting into stackoverflow. I have edited the question now.

Comment: What is the output of the console if you leave out `.startAt` and `.endAt`?

Answer (score 4):

I put your data into my Firebase database and run exactly your code. My output is:

```
{ '1234': { deliveryDate: 1460844000000, size: 45 } }
```

However, I had to modify the data you provided, because it isn't in a valid JSON format in your snipped - in other words it's not an object, so it cannot be a value stored in a Firebase node - maybe you made a typo or you're storying an array of objects instead of an object under that key as @TimVermeulen noticed in a comment below. I modified it to:

```
{
    "1234": {
        "size" : 45,
        "deliveryDate" : 1460844000000
    },
    "1342": {
        "size" : 23,
        "deliveryDate" : 1243845000000
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, it seems OP made an array of dictionaries each with a single key, rather than a dictionary with all the keys.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Yes it might be it

Comment: Indeed: after fixing the JSON structure, it works for me: http://jsbin.com/zakunoq/edit?js,console